# Linking a Fragment with its updates inside another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image: The Problem]

I have **2 fragments** which I **navigate using a ViewPager**,as you can see in the figure the **user first encounters Fragment 1 adds value in EditText then navigates to Fragment 2** .Inside Fragment 2**I want Fragment 1 to showup with the value that the user added**,however the fragment xml layout that I added and linked to Fragment 1 class shows its layout without the value which the user added.

**In Fragment 2 XML**

```
     <fragment
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
<!--Linking Fragment 1 class -->
                    class="com.example.acer.patinternational.Child"
                    android:name="com.example.acer.patinternational.Child"
                    android:tag="@string/app_name"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/f1"
<!--Linking Fragment 1 Layout-->
                    tools:layout="@layout/childinfo" />
```

This is not about how to put a Fragment inside another,but about getting a fragment context inside another.

Comment: Please correct me If I am wrong , You want your first fragment edit text to have what you have written after coming from the second fragment right ?

Comment: When going to the **second fragment**, inside it I want to see the **first Fragment** with the updated EditText